# How do I make two divs share a background when the top one is 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I have a rather technical design in mind. First, there should be a 100% height (with some min and max values) "banner" with a background image ideally set to cover it. Then, **outside** the view below, there should be a fixed height div **sharing the same background** except for darkening it a bit.

I threw together a mockup so the concept is clear:

[image: design example].

The problem can be illustrated with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx7xLrpx/), where I try to make the screen-covering div inside another div containing the background. That doesn't work because `height: 100%` requires all parents to have the same setting, but if I make the div with the background 100% then the bottom div comes into view again...

And as I figured, setting the top div to `height: 110%` or something like that and then working inside it doesn't produce the result I want. If I could set it to `100% + 200px` that would be great, but alas, I don't know how, nor do I know of a good workaround.

Anyone with a solution or good ideas, please throw them my way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about giving a padding bottom to the bankground div ?.That should solve the issue.

```
.background {
    background: url('http://www.mixflavour.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Nature-Wallpaper-03.jpg');
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.bottom-div {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Check out the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/kaa83qu7/

Comment: This is an even simpler solution and one that doesn't come with the caveat of incompatibility. My question feels silly now!

Answer (score 1):

Use calc to calculate the height of the background.

```
.background {
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% + 100px);
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.max-height {

}

.bottom-div {
    position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/jx7xLrpx/2/

Don't forget to check the browser support:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Damn, it's bittersweet when the solution is so simple, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calc in your css:

```
height: calc(100% + 200px);
```